# Google Play Store is unable to search for updates

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-services

I have a THL T9 Plus with Android 6.0. Google Play Store version is 8.5.39.W-all [PR]. Google Play Services is version 11.9.51. I try to install updates on phone, but I get the error message, "There was an error during update process." I can't see even new version of installed applications in the list.

I tried to force stop those processes, wipe caches, restart phone and I already updated Google Play Store client version, but none of these helped, I got same error message.

Comment: There are bunch of things you can try [mentioned here](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-store-not-working-fixes-647176/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are list of things can be done like uninstall updates and install fresh again, you can get a list of check [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-store-not-working-fixes-647176/)

Comment: Yes, fresh install seems a good solution, but where to found proper `apk` file?

Comment: It is a system app ; you can't uninstall or install. What you can do is to uninstall updates by Settings > Apps > Google Play Store and tap on “Uninstall updates”. Connect to Wi-Fi and your updates will be installed automatically